# On insert or update i want to update UPDATED_AT column with current timestamp

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, ddl

I'm getting this error **missing right parenthesis** near on update query in oracledb

Working fine with Mysql :

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE
    ADD COLUMN `updated_at` `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CurrENT_TIMESTAMP();
```

Not working with Oracle:

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE
ADD (
  UPDATED_AT DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no data type of `datetime` in Oracle.  There is a `date` which always has the day and the time to the second.  Or `timestamp` which includes fractional seconds.  Or `timestamp with [local] time zone` that includes a time zone.  Since you are using `current_timestamp`, I'll guess that you intended the data type to be `timestamp with time zone`.

There is also no `on update` property for a column.  If you want the column to be updated whenever the row is updated, you'd need to write a trigger for that.

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE
ADD (
  UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

create trigger set_updated_at
  before update on employee
  for each row
begin
  :new.updated_at := current_timestamp();
end;
```